# vscode shows an error message when `satisfies` keyword is used

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using typescript `4.9.4` on vscode. When I write a code with a newly-introduced `satisfies` keyword, there is no compile error but the editor shows an error when I save the file as `.ts` file.

```
type Test = {
  t1: string;
};

export const TEST_JSON = {
  t1: 't1',
} satisfies Test;
```

[image]

Here is an error from DevTools console. It is catched from `workbench.desktop.main.js:774`.

```
unknown: Missing semicolon. (7:1) 5 | export const TEST_JSON = { 6 | t1: 't1', > 7 | } satisfies Test; | ^ 8 |
```

I looked through google and github issues but have no idea. Any help on this?

For your reference, here is my vscode environment.

```
Version: 1.74.2
Commit: e8a3071ea4344d9d48ef8a4df2c097372b0c5161
Date: 2022-12-20T10:32:21.587Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.2.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: VSCode, [issue #166889](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166889): satisfies keyword showing with red underline (and defined as a constant)

Comment: @Andreas I'm using TS 4.9.4 version in my editor, and there is no red underline. It just shows popup on right bottom corner when a file (with satisfies keyword) is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I tried to disable extensions one by one and found the reason. https://github.com/kcmr/vsce-remove-unused-imports didn't support typescript `4.9.4`.

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/kcmr/vsce-remove-unused-imports/issues/24) and the author is looking into it.

Meanwhile, anyone interested can use this [fixed version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spilist.remove-unused-imports-ts-494). Note that it will be removed when the original author update the extension to solve the problem.